# What is ptcache and how do I use it?

Tags: python

I'm trying to duplicate the behaviour of blender's simulations, where they cache played frames to the timeline.

Would anyone be able to provide a basic example of ptcache in use? perhaps a basic example of moving an object each frame.

Is ptcache the right thing for this or am I completely in the wrong area? thanks